# Converter string para DateTime com .ParseExact()

Tags: c#, datetime

Estou tentando receber uma string digitada pelo usuário no formato *"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"*, porém sempre que utilizo uma data acima de 12:59 ocorre o seguinte erro:

> System.FormatException: 'String '25/06/2018 13:00' was not recognized
>   as a valid DateTime.'

Código:

```
DateTime inicio = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O formato de hora para 24h é "HH", maiúsculo, usando isso vai funcionar:

```
DateTime inicio = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

O formato "hh" é para 12h apenas, por isso está com esse erro.

Veja aqui funcionando: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0g6fXE

Mas no seu exemplo, que está tentando ler o valor digitado, deveria primeiro receber o valor digitado numa variável e validar o formato antes de tentar converter.